# How to find derivative of following function with product rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$f(x) = \frac{(3x^2 + x + 2)}{(x^2 + 1)}$

Its supposed to equal $\frac{(1 + 6x)}{(1 + x^2)} - \frac{2x (2 + x + 3x^2)}{(1+x^2)^2}$

I can't figure out how to get that

Comment: What exactly did you get?

Comment: take $3x^2+x+2$ as $u$ and $\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ as $v$ and apply $u.v$ rule.

Answer (score 0):

Take $3x^2+x+2=u$  and $\frac{1}{x^2+1}=v$ and apply the rule $u.v=u'v+uv'$.

Here you get $u'=6x+1$ and $v'=-\frac{2x}{(x^2+1)^2}$

You can solve it further.